# How can I show my SetPixels() texture changes without having to zoom my orthographic camera?

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, texture2d, orthographic

This is my first question here! I hope you'll bear with me. :)

I'm working on flood fills on Unity, and while I'm already able to fill shapes on my Texture2D, I can only see the changes when I zoom in with my orthographic camera. When I zoom out, it goes back to looking like the original image. What is also weird is that this happens in both my editor and my game scene, as well as when I build it on Android.

What could possibly be causing this? What can I do to prevent this? Am I missing something?

I've tried using images of different sizes, but it still behaves the same way.

This is what it looks like after filling a shape using `SetPixels()` when zoomed in. The red circle is originally white. Notice that the editor is not showing the change. The image's size is 1920x1080:

[image]

This is how it then looks like when you zoom out a bit. The game scene now doesn't show the change as well. I've also included the properties of the texture in the screenshot:

[image]

I also observed that it might not even be about the camera zoom, as the changed pixels also appear if I scale up the image in the inspector even if I don't zoom in as much:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are only setting the pixels for a specific mipmap value (level 0 by default), but you need to extend the changes to the mipmap level that the camera is currently viewing.

You can do this by calling `Texture2D.Apply()` with `updateMipMaps` set to `true` (which is the default) after you set the pixels for the mipmap level 0 (which is probably what you are already doing).

Comment: Oh good Lord! Thank you so much, @Ruzihm! I had the updateMipmaps parameter on my texture2D.Apply set to false! I don't even know what it did, so I have no I idea why I did that! Thank you also for making my first question a pleasant experience! :)

Answer (score 1):

You did not provide any code, so it is hard to tell what is really going on. From the description alone it sounds like a problem with mipmaps that weren't updated. Mipmaps are used to provide different resolutions of the same image so an appropriately sized version can be used depending on the size the texture is actually rendered at.

When using [`Texture2D.SetPixels()`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Texture2D.SetPixels.html) you always modify one specific mipmap level, i.e. one specifically sized version of the image. By default this is level 0, the base mipmap level, which holds the full size version.

From the description it sounds like after modifying the base mipmap level, you called [`Texture2D.Apply()`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Texture2D.Apply.html) with the `updateMipmaps` argument set to `false`, as the example shown in Texture2D.SetPixels() does. This prevents updating the other mipmap levels of the texture so only the full sized version has the changes and none of the others. When the texture is now rendered at a smaller scale (i.e. by its current zoom level, by zooming out or scaling down) the change does not show up, as the corresponding smaller mipmap was never updated.

The documentation in [`Texture2D.Apply()`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Texture2D.Apply.html) is a bit misleading:

> If `updateMipmaps` is true, the mipmap levels are recalculated as well, using the base level as a source. Usually you want to use true in all cases except when you've modified the mip levels yourself using `SetPixels`.

It implies that you don't want `updateMipmaps` in case you used `SetPixels`, but it really only means that in the sense that you don't want it if you modified all the individual mipmap levels using `SetPixels` (as the example in `SetPixels` does). If you only modified the base level, then you really do want to use `updateMipmaps = true` so that the other mipmap levels are updated automatically from the modified base.

Comment: Thank you, @mmlr! @Ruzhim came to the same conclusion on my mistake and the solution, but thank you as well for elaborating on it! :)